# Replace parameter value in Expression Tree

Tags: c#, linq, expression

After having searched for quite a while, I am still not finding the answer I am looking for.  I have found answers about adding and removing parameters from a tree, but not anything about replacing specific parameters.

My first method is working as I would like it to, I need to replace the partitionKey value with the Uri escaped value and then return the results un-escaped.

```
public override IList<T> GetRowEntityList(string partitionKey)
{
    IList<T> rowEntities =  base.GetRowEntityList(Uri.EscapeDataString(partitionKey));
    return rowEntities.Select(UnEscapeRowEntity).ToList();
}
```

The problem I am having is overriding this method to behave the same way.  I already know that type `T` has the properties `PartitionKey` and `RowKey` but can also have any other number of properties.

For a sample predicate:

```
x => x.RowKey == "foo/bar" && x.SomeValue == "test"
```

I would expect it to become

```
x => x.RowKey == Uri.EscapeDataString("foo/bar") && x.SomeValue == "test"
```

Is there a way to do this?

My base class uses this predicate to do a table lookup on a table containing entities of type `T` using a `Where(predicate)` call

```
public override IList<T> GetRowEntityList(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
{
    //modify predicate value here

    return base.GetRowEntityList(predicate);
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for a way to detect a comparison with `x.RowKey` to some string in the predicate, then return a new predicate identical to that, just with an escaped string?

Comment: Are you asking how to build the expression so the user only needed to provide a simple string?

Comment: @Shlomo Yes. I am looking to detect a comparison with x.RowKey or x.PartitionKey and escape those strings while keeping the rest of the expression intact.

Comment: @Justin Basically this class allows the user to provide the actual string values that are stored in the table to do a lookup(such as `"http://foo.com"`) and escapes them(since the table doesnt allow `/` in the PartitionKey or RowKey) without the user of the API having to handle that themselves.  I am just stuck trying to escape those values in the `Expression` like I do in the other method I have shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to implement an [ExpressionVisitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd323984.aspx):

```
class MyVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    protected override Expression VisitBinary(BinaryExpression node)
    {
        if(CheckForMatch(node.Left))
            return Expression.Equal(node.Left, Rewrite(node.Right));

        if(CheckForMatch(node.Right))
            return Expression.Equal(Rewrite(node.Left), node.Right);

        return Expression.MakeBinary(node.NodeType, Visit(node.Left), Visit(node.Right));
    }

    private bool CheckForMatch(Expression e)
    {
        MemberExpression me = e as MemberExpression;
        if(me == null)
            return false;

        if(me.Member.Name == "RowKey" || me.Member.Name == "PartitionKey")
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    private Expression Rewrite(Expression e)
    {
        MethodInfo mi = typeof(Uri).GetMethod("EscapeDataString");

        return Expression.Call(mi, e);
    }
}
```

I think that's right. It's a bit hard to test. Please note this will only work for the limited case of `(x => x.RowKey == "some string")`. It won't work for `(x => x.RowKey.Equals("somestring")`. It also won't work for `(x => x.RowKey() == "some string")`.

You then use the implemented visitor to re-write the predicate:

```
Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = (s => s.RowKey == "1 2");

ExpressionVisitor v = new MyVisitor();
Expression<Func<T, bool>> rewrittenPredicate = v.Visit(predicate);

//rewrittenPredicate then tests if s.RowKey == "1%202"
```

Comment: This is the approach I took, I had actually just finished writing the visitor I am using when I saw your answer here.

Comment: Well, thanks for the opportunity for me to dust that stuff off. :)